# Swift 4.2 - PickerView not showing Content

Tags: ios, swift

this code makes me really mad. I already read thousands of tutorials and stack overflow comments....

Please help me. The Picker just contains a blank grey screen.

Code here:

GenderPickerModel.swift

```
    import UIKit

class GenderPickerModel:  NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    let genderPickerData: [String] = ["male", "female"]

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return genderPickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return genderPickerData[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    } 
}
```

and used in a Controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var gender: UITextField!  
private var genderPickerView: UIPickerView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadProfile()
        prepareView()
    }

    func prepareView() {
        genderPickerView = UIPickerView.init()

        let gpModel = GenderPickerModel()

        genderPickerView?.delegate = gpModel
        genderPickerView?.dataSource = gpModel
        gender.inputView = genderPickerView;
        genderPickerView?.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
        genderPickerView?.reloadAllComponents()
    }
```

Comment: Why do you create the instance of GenderPickerModel and assigned to dataSource and delegate, Can you tell me this whole code in one controller or not?

Comment: i bet that if you will put break points inside the model it wont stop there, meaning the delegates not working

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav because this controller holds 5 PickerViews. I wanted to separate these from the Controller class

Comment: @ironRoei but why? Whats the difference in having a separate class for the data and including the code inside the calling controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you do not need to do the separate array of gender in pickerview class and you don't need to create the instance of pickerview.

**From this, you can see your datasource in your custompickerview**

```
/**
Controller code where you can create instantiate picker assign data 

*/
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!            
        let genderPickerData : [String] = ["male", "female"]

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            prepareView()
        }

        func prepareView() {

            genderPickerView = UIPickerView()

            let gpModel = GenderPickerModel()

            gpModel.data = genderPickerData

            gpModel.dataSource = gpModel
            gpModel.delegate = gpModel
            textField.inputView = gpModel

        }
    }

/**

Custom pickerview class where you can handle data 

*/
import UIKit

class GenderPickerModel: UIPickerView, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    var data = [String]()

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return data[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the content is still empty!  :(

Comment: I tried this code, it works it showing datasource in pickerview, because I mention you have to create a custom class of pickerview and implement?